# Angular ng-bootstrap ngbNav component the tab-content does not show on nav-tab click

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular10

I'm using ng-bootstrap nav component.if i click to nav-item change active tab correct but tab-content not showing.
I check in browser elements nav-item's child class "nav-link active" like this image

[image]

but tab-content's child class "tab-pane fade ng-star-inserted" and content not show

[image]

only if i refresh page default active tab-content's child class "tab-pane fade show active ng-star-inserted" show like this

[image]

so i dont change nav tab because show and active class not add tab-content child class

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I updated ng-bootstrap version from 8.0.0 to 9.0.0 and problem solved. They've edited lazy load events in this version.

Answer (score 1):

I updated ng-bootstrap version from 8.0.0 to 9.0.0 and problem solved. They've edited lazy load events in this version.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1584